# Creating an Application for different platforms/device

Tags: cross-platform, device, platform

I'm currently working on a application that would run on any device like: Windows Phone, Android Device, iPhone, and Blackberry without coding for every each of the platforms so it would not eat too much time in just coding.

What Application, Language, or Idea that would let me create an application for different platforms?

Thanks.

Comment: @matz3 Web App. you mean a Application that needed to be run on a Browser? or a Application alone?

Comment: yes, in a browser or as a "real" app that embedds a browser view with html, css and js (have a look at davids answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). It will allow you make mobile apps that will run in almost every mobile OS, building the layout in HTML+CSS and coding the logic in JavaScript. In case you have knowledge of these technologies, this one is a pretty good option, as with its API you can access most of the device features through JavaScript

Comment: Thank you for the answer david. I just want to ask, have you develop an application using `PhoneGap` before? because I'm confused with the guide of `PhoneGap`.

Comment: Yes, I have. At first it could be a bit confusing, but when you get used to it it's not. You just have to write your app with HTML+CSS for the design, and implement the logic in Javascript (attach events to buttons/links, page transitions... whatever you need). You'll take advantage of the PhoneGap Javascript API if you have to use some of the device's functionalities, such as GPS, notifications, etc.

Comment: You mean. I would code normally for HTML, CSS and Javascript by using notepad, dreamweaver, or any web development tools? because the guide has different topics: Getting started with android, iOS, and etc. Sorry if I'm asking you this but I would like to learn from the one who already used it.

Comment: Well, you can write the app using whichever tool or IDE you want. But I would recommend you using Eclipse for Android and Xcode for iOS. Why? Because, even if you wrote the app with another tool, you eventually would need those two to compile it for each device. You have your app in Javascript, Xcode and Eclipse have the iOS and Android SDK's, PhoneGap is the missing piece, the framework that will fill that gap and will "compile" your Javascript to run in the device as a native app (this is not technically true, but I think it makes it easier to understand)

Comment: btw, I just need to transfer the HTML file so i can use it to another IDE right?

Comment: You got it. You can write the HTML wherever you want, and then copy it in the `www` folder of your PhoneGap project